# Where to find all possible "Connection" header values?

Tags: http, websocket, http-headers

Where may I find all possible values of all HTTP headers with explanations and maybe with examples? For now I want to know all possible values of `Connection` header.

I'm reading WebSockets Protocol documentation (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) and there is a Client example request:

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

There is a `Connection: Upgrade` header here. What does value `Upgrade` mean? I tried to serch in Wiki, Mozilla and RFC docs but they do not have this info.

Comment: This is an HTTP header to tell the server that user would like to **upgrade** to websocket protocol

Answer (score 1):

The set of field values is open-ended (it depends on header field names, which is open-ended).

The definition of "connection" can be found here: http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#header.connection